# PHP Date only won't insert into Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a HTML form that has ~30 variables being inserted into mysql via php. All the other variables are inserting correctly except for the date. I have looked at many of the other questions posted here and elsewhere and have still come up empty.

Originally I just had 3 inputs on the HTML form (year, month, day) setup as so:

```
     <span class="form-sub-label-container" style="vertical-align: top">
        <input class="form-textbox" id="year_6" name="lengthOf[0]" type="date" value="" />
        <span class="date-separate"> &nbsp;- </span>
        <label class="form-sub-label" for="year_6" id="sublabel_year" style="min-height: 13px;"> Start Date </label>
      </span>

     <span class="form-sub-label-container" style="vertical-align: top">
        <input class="form-textbox" id="month_6" name="lengthOf[1]" type="date" size="2" maxlength="2" value="" />
        <span class="date-separate"> &nbsp;- </span>
        <label class="form-sub-label" for="month_6" id="sublabel_month" style="min-height: 13px;"> Month </label>
      </span>

     <span class="form-sub-label-container" style="vertical-align: top">
        <input class="form-textbox" id="day_6" name="lengthOf[2]" type="date" size="2" maxlength="2" value="" />
        <label class="form-sub-label" for="day_6" id="sublabel_day" style="min-height: 13px;"> Day </label>
      </span>
```

With the php for this portion being:

```
$LengthOfService = $_POST['lengthOf'][0]."-".$_POST['lengthOf'][1]."-".$_POST['lengthOf'][2];
```

A `print_r($LengthOfService)` would show a correctly formatted date yyyy-mm-dd, however in the column that holds the date (it is DATE type) it shows 0000-00-00.

SOOOOO, I then decided to try and change the input type on the HTML form to date so there would only be 1 POST variable to load instead of 3:

```
          <span class="form-sub-label-container" style="vertical-align: top">
            <input class="form-textbox" id="year_6" name="lengthOf" type="date" value="01/01/2000" />
            <label class="form-sub-label" for="year_6" id="sublabel_year" style="min-height: 13px;"> Start Date </label>
          </span>
```

so now the php was simply:

```
$LengthOfService = $_POST['lengthOf'];
```

That was still a no-fire, so kept kept on with the reading and decided to go a head and try to format it even though it seemed to be already formatted correctly.

```
$LenthOfService = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['lengthOf']));
```

Still showing up in the mysql column as 0000-00-00, all the while `print_r($LengthOfService)` still produced the correct format...

Just for reference this is how I'm inserting into mysql:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO table (ColumnNames) VALUES ('$Values')";

mysql_query($insert)
   or die (mysql_error());
```

Hopefully I've provided enough information for someone to either be able to tell what I'm doing wrong or any other steps I can try. I'm not getting any errors either.

Comment: What are the values for **$Values** variable?

Comment: It might have to do with how you're formatting the date. •DATE - format YYYY-MM-DD
•DATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS
•TIMESTAMP - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS
•YEAR - format YYYY or YY
I had a similar problem building a database recently.  Try changing your input to match the date format YYYY-MM-DD and see what results you get.

Comment: @NBPalomino There are 27 of them, I was just using table, ColumnNames, and $Values as representation of how I wrote the query.

Comment: @Tony I tried that 2 ways, by making the date POST variable loaded directly as the yyyy-mm-dd and by having php format it  strtotime, still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with:

```
$LenthOfService = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['lengthOf']));
$insert = "INSERT INTO table (ColumnNames) VALUES ('$LenthOfService')";
echo $insert;
```

and I got:

> INSERT INTO table (ColumnNames) VALUES ('2016-01-06')

I suggest that you check and make sure you are not passing NULL, for debugging, print the query like I just did above.

Comment: @zigwaldo what does the insert query look like, echo it!

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific and it wouldn't let me edit. I did echo it and got the same output you did, it showed the correct value for the variable.

Comment: What is your column type? Date , datetime or timestamp

Comment: Can you show the real code, u shouldnt be using mysql_ btw

Comment: Can you show your actual INSERT statement? Also, double check your spelling to ensure that your INSERT values correctly match the database column.